# Joomla home page not appearing in root

Tags: php, html, apache, joomla, content-management-system

I've installed Joomla (running on Ubuntu 14.04) according to the default installation guidelines. My problem is that now when I navigate to my domain (insertdomainhere.com) what shows up isn't my Joomla home, but the apache default page. At the moment I have to navigate to insertdomainhere.com/joomla to view my Joomla page. What I'd like to do is set it so that when I navigate to insertdomainhere.com my Joomla page appears (as opposed to .com/joomla).
Any and all help is greatly appreciated.
Cheers,
Ryan

Comment: So is your Joomla installation in the root of your site, or in a directory called *joomla*?

Comment: In a directory called joomla unfortunately, looking to set it to root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what shows up isn't my Joomla home, but the apache default page.

This is because you've uploaded Joomla! in `/joomla` and not in the default directory (`/var/www/html`). This would result in Apache showing the default page.

> What I'd like to do is set it so that when I navigate to insertdomainhere.com my Joomla page appears (as opposed to .com/joomla).

You should move your Joomla! installation to the root directory of your web server or put this in an `.htaccess` file in the root directory:

`Redirect 301 / /joomla`

Comment: @RyanDardis Great! :) For SEO reasons I recommend you move Joomla! to your root directory.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to redirect your root folder to /joomla/:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /joomla/
```